# Use map to return NA when element missing from nested list

Tags: r, list, purrr

I have a nested list:

```
test <- list(
  one = list(text = "String", number = "1"),
  two = list(text = "String"),
  three = list(text = "String", number = "3")
)
```

And I can use `map_chr(test, "text")` to return every text value, but how would I get `map_chr(test, "number")` to work and return:

```
one  two  three
"1"  NA   "3"
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48428107/purrrmap-df-drops-null-rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
map_chr(test, ~ pluck(., "number", .default = NA_character_))

  one   two three 
  "1"    NA   "3"
```

Or directly (suggested by @aosmith):

```
map_chr(test, "number", .default = NA_character_)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use .default directly in the map() function.

Comment: @aosmith this parameter is quite hidden, but you are right, it can be used directly :)

Answer (score 0):

We can also use a logical condition

```
library(purrr)
map_chr(test, ~ {val <- .x$number; replace(val, is.null(val), NA) })
#  one   two three 
#  "1"    NA   "3"
```